# How did the garbage bags work in Logan Lucky?

Tags: plot-explanation, logan-lucky

Towards the end of *Logan Lucky*, when it is explained how the heist *actually* went on, Channing Tatum dumps some bags of cash on this side of the wall (image). This happens when Daniel Craig goes to check on his brothers and Channing's sister (Riley Keough) comes down. The garbage bin though is on the other side, where it is later shown that Tatum dumps a few bags in it and recovers it from the landfill later. Why does Channing Tatum do this and why does his sister come down when Daniel Craig leaves?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Jimmy had earlier abandoned the main haul (money) and phoned in an anonymous tip to the police as to its whereabouts.

Yet, unknown to the others, during the heist, Jimmy had hid some money from the haul in extra trashbags, which he ends up putting in the trashbin and are then taken to the dump.

Later on, Jimmy retrieves 'his part' of the loot and uses it to buy a home near his daughter and ex-wife. He has gotten a good job at Lowes.

Because he phoned in the tip, the racetrack recovered most of the loot (they didn't know *exactly* how much was stolen, and were paid off by the insurance as well. The case was closed.

No one was searching for any more money, and Jimmy *paid* off the others, also anonymously: He left a bag of money buried in Joe's yards he digs up after leaving prison. Sylvia received an *anonymous* donation for her clinic as does the inmate who started the riot.

So, in the end, Jimmy steals money, returns most of it, anonymously, taking the police and FBI off the case, pays off the others, and (we assume) lives happily ever after, near his daughter.

Comment: Thank you very much. But one thing still remains unclear to me though, when Jimmy and Joe come back after helping the two brothers open the gate, we see Clyde collecting the money and bags around him on this side of the wall, and then Jimmy asks Joe and Clyde to leave and he is there by himself. So does that mean he had hid the rest of the bags on the other side of the wall (above picture) just to show Joe lesser number of bags when they both come down and then have both the sets of the bags (this side and the other side of the wall) get to the landfill?